# Updating element in array inside document with MongoDB not preserving its type

Tags: java, mongodb, database

In my project there is a structure like so:

```
class User {
  private List<MapObject> mapObjects;
}

class MapObject {
  ... some fields...
}

class SubMapObject {
  ... some additional fields
}
```

initially, User class is filled with data (and also including instances of SubMapObject class) from template and stored in MongoDB via MongoTemplate from the Spring integration, like so:

```
mongoOps.insert(u);
```

And the information of every entry in mapObjects field is preserved, also that of what **_class** it is. (in cases when it's subclass)

Then it comes to a point where we need to update a single element in the mapObjects field of User. We do it like that:

```
mongoOps.updateFirst(
                query(where("_id").is(userObjectId).and("mapObjects._id")
                        .is(mo.get_id())), update("mapObjects.$", mo),
                User.class);
```

Where **mo** is SubMapObject for instance.

Whenever any sub class (of MapObject) instance is passed, the information regarding what class it is (the _class) field in the MongoDB record of that object, is lost, it is treated like its parent - the MapObject. So we have the following questions :)

1) Where do we do wrong and how to preserve the information for this object's class?

2) Furthermore, we were wondering if it is faster to update the whole mapObjects field than updating only particular element in it (because it has to iterate in this case to find it). Most likely a single User would have 300-400 entries in its mapObjects list.

Comment: Seeing the same issue with a custom push implementation. What's strange is that the object's fields are mapped using the custom converter but the object itself doesn't preserve the _class field.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across this and managed a solution. I assume you are also using the Spring Data for MongoDB Repository interface, if so see this related question here: [How would I do $push using MongoRepository in Spring Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14247573) for more details.

The basic idea is that once you've wired up the custom class for your Repository then the last step is to use to also inject the mongo mapping converter from your context. Then rather than pass off your object, you first convert it to a DBObject and save that DBObject instead. The converter should write out a _class field as expected.